# Lambda template variable (static constexpr) inside template class - unexpected expression of kind template_parm_index

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, compiler-errors, template-variables

I'm trying to define a lambda template variable (`static constexpr`) inside of a template class.  The template variable takes in a NTTP, which I want to be a `size_t`.

I'm able to do so in certain situations, like if the NTTP is `auto` instead of `size_t`.  I'm also able to do so if the class itself isn't a template class.  But if I try to use a NTTP (`size_t`) for the lambda within a template class, I get:

`internal compiler error: unexpected expression ‘<enumerator>’ of kind template_parm_index`

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/Sk3wC7nyP

Code below:

```
template<size_t>
struct Foo{
    // internal compiler error: unexpected expression ‘<enumerator>’ of kind template_parm_index
    template<size_t>
    static constexpr auto foo = [](){};
};

template<size_t>
struct Bar{
    // OK
    template<auto>
    static constexpr auto foo = [](){};
};

struct Baz{
    // OK
    template<size_t>
    static constexpr auto bar = [](){};
};
```

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug in `gcc 7`, the code compiles fine with `gcc 8` and newer. [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/4q43sb)

Comment: @IlCapitano: Looks like? No, an "internal compiler error" is always a bug :-) Simply use a up to date compiler. Current release is 10.1. So please forget the fully outdated 7 series.